# Understanding the Schwarz Reflection Principle,

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

The way I understand the principle is that we look at F, piecewise-defined as:

F= $$ z \mapsto f(z), \ z \in \Omega^+$$
$$ z \mapsto \overline{f(\bar z)}, \ z \in \Omega^-$$

Here $\Omega^+$ and $\Omega^-$ are symmetric with respect to the real axis.

Then F is *the* analytic continuation of f to the lower half space.  With Morera's Theorem, F is shown to be analytic on the real axis, and so is analytic on the whole of $\Omega$.

Have I understood the Reflection Principle correctly, or am I making things up to convince myself that this is what the theorem is saying?

To justify that $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is indeed analytic, I look at its power series, which is $\sum \bar a_n z^n$, but this is just the power series of the function f that was initially defined - and analytic - on the upper half space, except that the coefficients are now conjugated.  Is this enough (even obvious?) to say that $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is analytic, from looking at its power series?  I am guessing it is, since the conjugation of z does not change the modulus of z, and all the convergence tests, e.g., ratio test, would give exactly the same convergence results that was gotten for the original function f.

Thanks,

Comment: You also need to have real boundary values on the real axis. This implies that $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, agreed, @robjohn.  I left out some assumptions (also need f(z) to continuously extend to the real axis), since I figured the audience answering my question will know the theorem already.  What do you think of my idea for arguing that $\bar f(z¯)$ is analytic, by looking at its power series?

Comment: Hi, @orangeskid - did you mean to also conjugate the complex coefficients?  Just want to make sure.  So, the argument is that the convergence result is the same, and since this is a convergent power series around $\bar z_0$, then f¯(z¯) is analytic near $\bar z_0$ - since a convergent power series, in the complex variables setting, always corresponds to a complex-analytic function.  Do I have it right, mostly?  Thanks,

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need to conjugate the $a_n$ too, so $f(z) = \sum_n \bar a_n (z-\bar z_0)^n$ around $\bar z_0$. I should remove the previous comment since it is wrong.

Comment: So the idea is: reflexion $\circ$ analytic fn $\circ$ reflexion is again analytic. And these reflexions could be also wr to some circles ( i e inversions).

Comment: Since you mentioned it, how *would* we reflect over an arc of circle, since the theorem is nicely stated for reflection across the real line, and the extension function is easily the conjugation of f.  How would we find those other extension functions when reflecting over something else that is not the real line?

Comment: Let's see: you have a function analytic on the upper half plane, continuous on the closed upper half plane and real on the real axis. Define the function on the closed lower half plane $z \mapsto \overline{ f(\bar z)}$. This coincides with the previous function on $\mathbb{R}$, is analytic on the lower halfplane and moreover, is continuous ( being continuous on each of the two close pieces). Now Morera shows that $f$ is analytic ( it's enough to have Morera for every rectangle with sides parallel to the axes, and this is easy to check)

Comment: If you want to reflect across circles, you need two of them, the function being defined on one side of the circle $C_1$, holomorphic and continuous up to $C_1$, and mapping $C_1$ to $C_2$. Define the function from the other side of $C_1$ as $r_{C_2} \circ f \circ r_{C_1}$, where we denote by $r_C$  the reflexion ( inversion in fact) wr to the circle $C$. You have an extension to the other side of $C_1$. This may work for domains whose boundaries consist of pieces of circles.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder that the extension function must match f on the "overlap", in this case the overlap is the real line, but conjugation has no effect on real numbers, so the two functions indeed match on the overlap, and the extension function is indeed *the* analytic continuation of f (to the lower half space.)

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for your help, @orangeskid.

Comment: Actually, just one last follow-up question, if you don't mind, @orangeskid: do you have a book to recommend that is particularly good with explaining conformal mappings and applications of the Schwarz Reflection Principle to some tricky problems?  I am thinking that I better stop reading Ahlfors until I read something a little easier.

Comment: @user245678: Some people like Zeev Nehari's book 'Conformal Mapping", seems good from the content.